Is my answer correct? Method of characteristics
Consider the problem $xu_x-yu_y=0$ where $u(x,x) = f(x^2)$.

My Answer:
Suppose that $x\neq 0$ then $u_x-\frac{y}{x}u_y=0.$ So let be $\varphi(x)= u(x,y(x))$, derivating this expression we get
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dx}\varphi(x)= u_x(x,y(x))+u_y(x,y(x))y'(x).
\end{align*}
So the later expression will be zero if $y'(x)=-y/x$ and $y(a)=a$ (here is my first question about my answer, whit this initial condition we can get the Characteristic curve with de initial values but this Characteristics will not be cover all space only first and third regions in the plane) then $y(x)=\frac{a^2}{x}$ (is these all characteristic curves?).
Following the idea of characteristic curves we get that $u(x,y)=f(xy)$ but only in $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)\cup (-\infty,0)\times (-\infty,0)$, evidently we can verify that this is a solution of the PDE in all $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I wondering if there is curves that I'm not considering.
Thank you.

Your solution is correct, but not unique. Any function
$$
u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
f(xy)&\text{if $xy\geq 0$,} \\
g(xy)&\text{if $xy<0,$}
\end{cases}
$$
where $g$ is differentiable, $g(0^-)=f(0)$, and $g'(0^-)=f'(0^+)$, also is a solution to the PDE satisfying $u(x,x)=f(x^2)$. (See this similar question.)

$$xu_x-yu_y=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{du}{0}$$
If you prefer you can write $\begin{cases} dx=x\:ds\\dy=-y\:ds\\du=0\:ds \end{cases}\quad$ getting rid of the questionable limits at $x=0$ and $y=0$ .
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}$
Or if you prefer  $\begin{cases} dx=x\:ds\\dy=-y\:ds \end{cases}\quad ydx=-xdy$ :
$$xy=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE from the implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u(x,y)=F(xy)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
CONDITION : $u(x,x)=f(x^2)$ where $f$ is a given (known) function.
Putting this condition into the general solution leads to
$$u(x,x)=F(x*x)=f(x^2)$$
The function $F$ is equal to the given function $f$.
Thus $F$ is known now. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $xy$.
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=f(xy)}$$
This solution satisties both the PDE and the condition.
For example :
If the given function is $f=\sin$
the solution $\quad u(x,y)=\sin(xy)\quad $ satisfies  both the PDE and the condition without particular case for $x=0$ and/or $y=0$ and without distinction between negative and/or positive $x$ and $y$ cases.
NOTE: Of course if the given function $f$ is a picewise function made of several different functions, the solution $u(x,y)=f(xy)$ will be a picewise function as well with different equations in different domains.
